# Unable to start Node JS service using node-windows

Tags: node.js

I have installed `node-windows` module and created windows service using below script. It has created  a windows service , however, it is not starting and throwing below error

**Script to create service**

```
 var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

    // Create a new service object
    var svc = new Service({
      name:'Node HtmlToPDF',
      description: 'Node JS Application which converts Html String to PDF',
      script: 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\eclipse-workspace\\HtmlToPDF\app.js',
      wait: 2,
      grow: .5
    });


    // Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
    // process is available as a service.
    svc.on('install',function(){
      svc.start();
    });

    svc.install();
```

Below is the message it throws when i try to start and it never starts. Is there any other configuration needs to be done? I have tried to start with `SC START` and also with `NET START` but didn't work

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc start nodehtmltopdf.exe

SERVICE_NAME: nodehtmltopdf.exe
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 17888
        FLAGS              :

C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start nodehtmltopdf.exe
The Node HtmlToPDF service is starting.
The Node HtmlToPDF service was started successfully.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake and after updating the path as below, it worked. Missed one slash on last.

```
script: 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\eclipse-workspace\\HtmlToPDF\\app.js'
```